# How to use Theano/TensorFlow/Keras for running SGD without neural nets?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, theano, keras

Given a model equation, a specific loss function and gradients (that I've already derived), how do I use something like Theano/TensorFlow (or Keras since it's more generic) to train the model without using neural nets?

I simply want to use SGD to minimize the regularized logistic loss. Is this a good example: http://www.deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html ?

Equations (1) and (2) of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.04935v2.pdf are, for instance, something I'm trying to work with.

Comment: And `sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor` doesn't cover what you need? (To answer your question: Of course you can do that. Just write the loss out in the way the framework of your choice would like to have it formulated.)

Comment: @eickenberg I want to try out the data and model parallelism in TensorFlow. I could do it with Spark's GradientDescent Optimizer too, but TensorFlow can run on GPUs, and even when running on CPUs in parallel it might be faster since it's built on C++/Python - that's what I'm trying to verify.

Comment: A neural net with with no hidden layers and logistic loss is the same as logistic regression